# Order sender file is not ovverriding

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

My di.xml file is

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender" type="ABC\Listrak\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender" />
</config>
```

My class

```
namespace ABC\Listrak\Model\Order\Email\Sender;

class OrderSender extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender
{   
    public function __construct(
            \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    )
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function send(Order $order, $forceSyncMode = false)
    {
        $order->setSendEmail(true);

        if (!$this->globalConfig->getValue('sales_email/general/async_sending') || $forceSyncMode) {
            if ($this->checkAndSend($order)) {
                $order->setEmailSent(true);
                $this->orderResource->saveAttribute($order, ['send_email', 'email_sent']);
                return true;
            }
        }

        $this->orderResource->saveAttribute($order, 'send_email');

        return false;
    }


}
```

But i get Error

```
Warning: Declaration of ABC\Listrak\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender::send(ABC\Listrak\Model\Order\Email\Sender\Order $order, $forceSyncMode = false) should be compatible with Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender::send(Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order, $forceSyncMode = false) in C:\wamp64\www\huf\app\code\ABC\Listrak\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender.php on line 41
```

If someone can help with this 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Class file `OrderSender.php` content should like this.

```
namespace ABC\Listrak\Model\Order\Email\Sender;

use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;

class OrderSender extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender
{   
    public function __construct(
            \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    )
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function send(Order $order, $forceSyncMode = false)
    {
        $order->setSendEmail(true);

        if (!$this->globalConfig->getValue('sales_email/general/async_sending') || $forceSyncMode) {
            if ($this->checkAndSend($order)) {
                $order->setEmailSent(true);
                $this->orderResource->saveAttribute($order, ['send_email', 'email_sent']);
                return true;
            }
        }

        $this->orderResource->saveAttribute($order, 'send_email');

        return false;
    }
}
```

I have added `use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;` after `namespace ABC\Listrak\Model\Order\Email\Sender;`.

Comment: Welcome @Impunkj, happy to help!